# When do HTTP requests happen in managed beans (depending on their scopes)?

Tags: jsf, scope, httprequest

Does a `session scoped` managed bean have an HTTP request per method? How can I know when an HTTP request starts and ends?

And what's the difference for a `view scoped` managed bean? (still concerning the HTTP requests)

And for a `request scoped` managed bean, does it have only one HTTP request for the entire managed bean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I know when an HTTP request starts and ends?

You can use [***Fiddler***](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) to inspect HTTP requests/responses

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol is what a browser uses to communicate with a web server. Specifically, the browser sends an HTTP request to the server, which sends a back an HTTP response.

Therefore, HTTP requests don't happen *in* a bean. At most, a managed bean may be *used* for processing an HTTP request on the server.

The scope of a managed bean definition controls the sharing of bean instances:

- If the bean has request scope, a dedicated bean object is used for every request.
- If the bean has session scope, a dedicated bean object is used for every user session (i.e. all requests from the same user are processed using the same bean object).
- If the bean has view scope, a dedicated bean object is used for every JSF view (i.e. as long as the user doesn't navigate to another page, all requests are processed using the same bean object)

> How can I know when an HTTP request starts and ends?

It's unclear what you mean by a request starting or ending.

> But I need to get those attributes at the first request of a use case, and then for all the other requests for the same use case.And when the use case is done,I need to clear the map with those attributes.

The idiomatic way to control the lifetime of state is to keep it in a bean with suitably long scope. If your use case only has a single view, a view scoped bean would fit nicely.

Otherwise, if it is only for a few views, I'd have the view scoped beans aggregate a conversation object, and pass that conversation object to the next view scoped bean upon navigation. That way, you won't need to take any special action when the user aborts the usecase (which he can typically do in many ways, for instance by using the main navigation ...).

If you have a big application any many such multi-view usecases, you might want to check out the many libraries that offer a *conversation scope*.

Comment: Let me try to explain it more clearly: I nee to get the session attributes, like this: ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();                                    But I need to get those attributes at the first request of a use case, and then for all the other requests for the same use case.And when the use case is done,I need to clear the map with those attributes. That's why I'd like to know when those http requests happen.I Hope it's clearer, sorry I'm new to this web world.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I have extended my answer accordingly.